# NullReferenceException when browsing Sitecore Content Tree

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a Sitecore 6.4 installation (Sitecore.NET 6.4.1 (rev. 110621)), deployed to two servers in a load balanced environment. For one (and only one) of the servers, when you are browsing the content tree in the content editor you receive a stack trace as below. It doesn't always error, but once you do see the error it always happens.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +1636

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +639
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +37
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +66
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +420
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how your load balancing is configured? Are these Delivery or Management servers? Have you properly set up your two servers according to the Scaling Guide?

Comment: Both servers are delivery & management - we don't distinguish between the two. They do use sticky IP. The ScalabilitySettings.config was renamed, but no values were updated (they are all defaults).

Answer (score 0):

As @techphoria414 says, make sure you have read the [Scalability Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx) and also make sure you have renamed `..Website\App_Config\Include\ScalabilitySettings.config.example` to `ScalabilitySettings.config` and checked the various settings inside that config.